# Как записать данные в переменную объекта заданную через lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expressions

У меня есть некоторый класс `MyClass1` и объект этого класса `myClass1`.
Заданна некоторая Lambda `x=>x.SomeField`

Класс и лямбда заранее не известны, они передаются параметрами.

```
Set(myClass1,x=>x.SomeField) // эту функцию нужно реализовать
```

Мне нужно в `myClass1.SomeField` положить некоторое значение. Как это можно сделать?

Как я понимаю это можно сделать на основе `Expressions` но что-то пока не понял как.

Comment: а какое значение?

Comment: @Grundy объект, класс тоже не известен заранее. Я уже понял как - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601707/how-to-set-property-value-using-expressions

Comment: Объявить по месту использования myClass1 как dynamic, или уходить в рефлексию.

Comment: В довольно простом случае можно так: `public static void Set<T, U>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, U>> getter)
        {
            MemberExpression me = (MemberExpression)getter.Body;
            var t = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(Expression.Assign(me, Expression.Constant(default(U), typeof(U))), getter.Parameters);
            t.Compile().Invoke(obj);
        }` единственное что - компиляция выражения каждый раз